# Is it possible to block Chrome extensions Like Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to block Chrome extensions Like Adobe Acrobat?

The issue Adobe Acrobat can convert my img.

How to detect and redirect? Or perhaps block convert to pdf.

Comment: So, you goal is to prevent image theft?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to check if an user has a certain chrome extention installed.

**Firstly:** We search the extention manifest for `"web_accessible_resources"`, in the case of Adobe Acrobat there is one: `"data/js/frame.html"`.

**Secondly:** 
We create the url to the resource: "chrome-extension://" + PLUGIN_ID + "data/js/frame.html".

The plugin id can be found in the url of the plugin page: www.chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-acrobat/*efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj* (PLUGIN_ID in italics)

**Finally:**
We check if the file exists with ajax, if it does Adobe Acrobat is installed.

```
function blockAcrobat(){

  $.ajax({
      url: "chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/data/js/frame.html",
      type: 'HEAD',
      error: function () {
          // File does not exist so Acrobat is not installed, do nothing
      },
      success: function () {
          // File does exist so Acrobat is installed, replace all images with a kitten image.
            $('img').attr('src', 'https://maxenluna.nl/uploads/kennisbank/de/-b/de-beste-tips-voordat-je-een-kitten-in-huis-neemt.jpeg');

      }
  });

}

blockAcrobat();
```

---

And here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rm6ehd8t/6/. If Adobe Acrobat  is installed you wil see the image of a cat. Open the JSFiddle with edge to see the other image of a business presentation.

P.S. Don't use these images in a production script lol.